# No loguea ningun usuario

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente codigo para login, pero no me reconoce ni usuario ni contraseña. Me da error de usuario o contraseña incorrecta.
No arroja ningun error de codigo o conexion de base de datos, no puedo ubicar donde esta la falla.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token']!=='') {
            
    //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    include "../config/config.php";

    $usuario=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["usuario"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $clave=sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["clave"],ENT_QUOTES)))));

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (mail =\"$usuario\" OR usuario=\"$usuario\") AND clave = \"$clave\";");

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                header("location: ../dashboard.php");
                

        }else{
            $invalid=sha1(md5("Contraseña y Usuario invalido"));
            header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
        }
    }else{
        header("location: ../");
    }
?>
```

```
<?php 
                    $invalid=sha1(md5("Contraseña y Usuario invalido"));
                    if (isset($_GET['invalid']) && $_GET['invalid']==$invalid) {
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in' role='alert'>
                            <strong> Error! </strong> Contraseña o Usuario Invalido
                            </div>";
                    }
                ?>
```

Me da error de usuario y contraseña, pero tanto aca como en el index, esta apuntando bien a la BD. Sumo la conexion como esta hecha, es localhost.

```
<?php

/*Datos de conexion a la base de datos*/
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');//DB_HOST:  generalmente suele ser "127.0.0.1"
define('DB_USER', 'root');//Usuario de tu base de datos
define('DB_PASS', '');//Contraseña del usuario de la base de datos
define('DB_NAME', 'tickets');//Nombre de la base de datos

$con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if(!$con){
    @die("<h2 style='text-align:center'>Imposible conectarse a la base de datos! </h2>");
}
if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    @die("Conexión falló: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

?>

Comment: Por favor, [edit] la pregunta y añade exactamente qué error te sale. De paso, revisa qué sale en los logs de PHP y lo añades también

Comment: Editado, no me arroja error de PHP, solo me da error de usuario y contraseña.

Comment: Para comprobar que la consulta está bien, prueba separar `$query = mysqli_query( ... )` en una variable previa con la consulta, por ejemplo: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM ..."`, luego dale `echo $sql;`, copia lo que eso genera y ejecútalo directo en phpmyadmin a ver qué sale.

Comment: Realizo esa consulta en phphmyadmn¡in y me trae los resultados.

Comment: @Diego... que funcione en phpmyadmin no quiere decir que en tu codigo funcione correctamente... si te piden que hagas pruebas y indique el resultado de esas pruebas por favor haslas ... de lo contrario no nos llevara a ningun lado lo que digas que no tenga que ver con las instrucciones nadas.